# Bash - split text file in columns by position/indexes

Tags: awk, multiple-columns

I have a text file with a structure similar to:

```
2013-11-22 eps Ind      2400000.23551544    100.    
2013-11-22 eps Ind      2400000.23551544    100.    
2013-11-22 eps Ind      2400000.23551544    100.    
2013-11-22 HD 217987    2400000.23551544    900.        
2013-11-22 TOI-134      2400000.23551544    900.    
2013-11-22 tau Cet      2400000.23551544    60.     
2013-11-22 BD+01   316  2400000.23551544    300.    
2013-11-22 BD+01   316  2400000.23551544    300.    
2013-11-22 BD+01   316  2400000.23551544    300.    
2013-11-22 BD+01   316  2400000.23551544    300.
```

and I need to extract it using bash. The main issue I have is that although the columns are tab separated, the names in column might have tabs or spaces, so with using `awk` gives me in some cases the wrong columns. How can I separate the text file in columns, but by index? All columns have the same width in characters -- considering space is a character. Each column has a different width.

Note that `eps Ind`, `HD 217987` and `BD+01   316` are all on the same column.

Thanks
Jorge

Comment: @EdMorton: I am considering that space is a character, am I wrong to do so? Anyway, I've updated my question

Comment: @EdMorton: `BD+01 316` is just one field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input really is fixed-width fields as you said (I'm assuming that's what you meant by `all columns have the same width in characters` rather than that all fields are the same width as each other within and across all lines) then using GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FIELDWIDTHS = "11 13 20 *"
    OFS = ","
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"",$i)
        printf "[%d]=\"%s\"%s", i, $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
[1]="2013-11-22",[2]="eps Ind",[3]="2400000.23551544",[4]="100."
[1]="2013-11-22",[2]="eps Ind",[3]="2400000.23551544",[4]="100."
[1]="2013-11-22",[2]="eps Ind",[3]="2400000.23551544",[4]="100."
[1]="2013-11-22",[2]="HD 217987",[3]="2400000.23551544",[4]="900."
[1]="2013-11-22",[2]="TOI-134",[3]="2400000.23551544",[4]="900."
[1]="2013-11-22",[2]="tau Cet",[3]="2400000.23551544",[4]="60."
[1]="2013-11-22",[2]="BD+01   316",[3]="2400000.23551544",[4]="300."
[1]="2013-11-22",[2]="BD+01   316",[3]="2400000.23551544",[4]="300."
[1]="2013-11-22",[2]="BD+01   316",[3]="2400000.23551544",[4]="300."
[1]="2013-11-22",[2]="BD+01   316",[3]="2400000.23551544",[4]="300."
```

Comment: that looks perfect, even better than I expected, thanks! :)

Comment: What if I wanted to pass variables instead of values to the `FIELDWIDTHS` parameter? e.g. `$w1`,`$w2`,`$w3`,... ? I've tried both `'$w1 $w2 $w3'` and `"$w1 $w2 $w3"` and I get something like `invalid FIELDWIDTHS value, near $w1 $w2 $w3'`

Comment: Assuming that when you say `variables` you mean **shell** variables as opposed to **awk** variables, remove setting `FIELDWIDTHS = "11 13 20 *"` from the script and then set it on the command line by calling awk as `awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="$w1 $w2 $w3 *" -f tst.awk file`. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for how to pass the value of shell variables to an awk script.

Comment: sorry, yes, I mean shell variables.

Comment: OK, so now you know - let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the `cut` tool to split the data into columns.

EDIT: If you have possible tabs *within* columns, but a fixed field with, use `cut` with character positions:

```
cut -c 12-24,45-50 file.txt
```

Comment: The OP said fields can contain tabs so you can't rely on tabs as the field separator - `The main issue I have is that although the columns are tab separated, the names in column might have tabs`

Comment: Heinrich: That was my first tough, but as @EdMorton pointed out, the main issue I have is that although the columns are tab separated, the names in column might have tabs.

Comment: Sorry, overread that on the first go. Edited accordingly. I still recommend cut, but with `-c` (or `-b`) to seperate at specific char/byte positions instead of `-d` to seperate at a specific delimiter.

Comment: Heinrich: cool, that appears to do the trick as well, thanks! :)

Comment: Heinrich: Any advantage/disavantage over @EdMorton's method? It does look simpler to understand....

Comment: @jorgehumberto Well, it's quite short and easily adaptable. E.g. when you have a fixed delimiter, but variable field width, you can use -d $'\t' -f 2,4 to select tab-separated columns 2 and 4.

Comment: @jorgehumberto you do understand that mine is more complicated because it's doing more than just printing fields, e.g. looping through fields removing leading/trailing white space and providing formatted output, right? If you just wanted to do what Heinrichs `cut` is doing that'd just be `awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="11 13 20 *" '{print $2, $4}'` and you can easily do a LOT more with that starting point than if you start with `cut`.

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes, I do understand, just wanted to know advantages/disadvantages of one over the other. Still haven't decided which method is best for my case, using `cut` looks simpler, but `awk` appears more powerful. In particular, I wan to investigate on how to use `awk` to also remove the tabs in the second column. Once I've tested both, I'll select the best answer. Thank you both!

Comment: `I wan to investigate on how to use awk to also remove the tabs in the second column.` - that's simply adding `gsub(/\t/,"",$2)`. Trivial, which is my point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach which uses Python. A little known secret is Python can be an outstanding text processing tool.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import fileinput
import sys

# Write comma-separated values (CSV) to standard output
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

# For each line of the input, split into columns,
# strip off the leading and trailing white spaces,
# then write the output
for line in fileinput.input():
    columns = [
            line[:11].strip(),    # Index 0 to 10
            line[11:24].strip(),  # Index 11 to 23
            line[24:44].strip(),  # Index 24 to 43
            line[44:].strip()     # The rest
    ]
    writer.writerow(columns)
```

#### Invoking the script

```
python script.py data.txt
```

#### Output

```
2013-11-22,eps Ind,2400000.23551544,100.
2013-11-22,eps Ind,2400000.23551544,100.
2013-11-22,eps Ind,2400000.23551544,100.
2013-11-22,HD 217987,2400000.23551544,900.
2013-11-22,TOI-134,2400000.23551544,900.
2013-11-22,tau Cet,2400000.23551544,60.
2013-11-22,BD+01   316,2400000.23551544,300.
2013-11-22,BD+01   316,2400000.23551544,300.
2013-11-22,BD+01   316,2400000.23551544,300.
2013-11-22,BD+01   316,2400000.23551544,300.
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this particular case I wanted bash. If in python I would most likely use `numpy`'s `genfromtxt` to do everything for me.